mutate_all changes date back to integer (time stamp)
When I use mutate_all in the following example, it changes my date time variable back to a time stamp (integer). Anyone know why?
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
    time_stamp = c(1687514217,1687514337,1687514457),
    value = c(55, NaN, 21))

df <- df |>
    mutate(date_time=as_datetime(time_stamp, tz='EST5EDT'))

df2 <- df |>
    mutate_all(~ifelse(is.nan(.), NA, .))


ifelse() strips attributes - this is expressly documented.  Use dplyr::if_else() instead. Also,  mutate_all() is superseded in favor of mutate(across(everything())).

Copy - thanks, @Iroha!
